# LDAP distinguished name

Tags: ldap

What command should I use to get value of the distinguished name?
I tried to use `ldaupwhoami`, but it returns me 4 additional lines, that begin with SASL.

```
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: mzhurba@...
SASL SSF: 112
SASL data security layer installed.
dn:uid=mzhurba,ou=july,ou=2018,ou=people,dc=....,dc=ua
```

How to get only the last line in format `uid=...,ou=2018,ou=...,dc=...,dc=..`

Comment: Provide the full output from the command that gives you your DN. Obfuscate if you need to do so, but keep it self-consistent

Comment: I need to get only this string: uid=mzhurba,ou=july,ou=2018,ou=people,dc=....,dc=ua

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the result through a `sed` command that matches on the leading `dn:` and prints everything else on (just) that line.

```
ldapwhoami | sed -n 's/^dn://p'
```